# How can client send a value to server using SignalR and the server update a model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

If I want to update a model/DB using SignalR, how is this achieved? (The other way around, i.e. from Server to Client is explained in many tutorials, but this way?)

So say we have a simple Model

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

And the corresponding View has an input field for the name. The hub is something like

```
public class UserHub : Hub
{
    public void UpdateName(string value)
    {
        // now what?

        Clients.All.updateTheViewIfNecessary(string newValue);

    }
}
```

**Edit**
How do I update the model, i.e. how do I achieve the same result as in the *regular* CRUD *edit* controller

```
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? What use case are you trying to address here ?

Comment: Use 3-Tier Architecture instead of MVC to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of this example we will use a JS client to send a model to the Hub and references official documentation at

[ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client: **How to call server methods from the client**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-call-server-methods-from-the-client)

Assuming a User Hub on the server

```
public interface IUserService {
    bool UpdateName(string userName);
    // Other methods not shown.
}

public class UserHub : Hub {
    private readonly IUserService service;

    public UserHob(IUserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void UpdateName(string value) {
        if(value != null) {
            var newValue = value;
            if(service.UpdateName(newValue) == true) {                    
                Clients.All.updateTheViewIfNecessary(newValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference documentation at [Dependency Injection in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) to understand how to inject dependencies into the hub. In the above `UserHub` when the message is received, it uses the data in the model to update/persist data via the injected dependency and notifies clients based on the result of that operation. This could allow for long running processes that could later update clients as needed.

A JavaScript client code that invokes the server method (assuming with the generated proxy) would look something like this.

```
//This assumes View has an input field for the name
var message = "Test Name";
userHubProxy.server.updateName(message).done(function () {
    console.log ('Invocation of UpdateName succeeded');
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log('Invocation of UpdateName failed. Error: ' + error);
});
```

The framework will handle whatever model binding needs to be done on the server.

The hub in effect acts as a service endpoint and sends the response of calling the service to all clients connected to it.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but do you mind changing the answer such, that the method `UpdateName` takes a string as argument and only the name is changed, not the whole object? Somehow, (without having tested it) it seems, that the Interface is taking different input arguements (string, id)

Comment: @RobertStettler were you able to review the documentation and test this.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I get "SignalR invoked UpdateName" but then nothing happens, neither does a breakpoint react nor does the `done` or `fail` method in js do anything. I believe there is a different error. Don't worry, I didn't forget you

Comment: It doesn't work at all. Where exactly do you expect the modify do happen? I can't see that

Comment: @RobertStettler, via the injected service whose implementation would be the one doing the actual modification. I ask again, have you reviewed the documentation and followed the examples provided there? Update the question with what you have done that is not working so we can work through solving the problem.

Comment: Yes, I read it through, and I see no connection to my question. It's about how to broadcast and not, how do you connect a specific client to a specific object and how to update it. Right now I solved it by adding cookies and register which client receives which object (model), but it doesn't look elegant to me.

Answer (score 1):

Call the server function to pass the values like shown in the javascript below.

I have also include the sample html table containing list of users to call server function against each button click

```js
    <table id="tblData">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="User 1" /> </td>
            <td><button type="button" value="2" title="User 2">User 2</button></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="User 3" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="User 4" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
var userId, userName, strOtherVal;
userId = 1; // sample values
userName = 'ali';
strOtherVal = 'admin';

         $(function () {
            $("#tblData tr td button,input").click(function (event) {

                 myHub.server.sendData(userId, userName, strOtherVal)
                    .fail(function (error) {
                        console.log('error sending data: ' + error)
                    });
                
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

On the server side your function will look like this

```
 public void sendData(int userId, string userName, string strOtherVal)
        {
            //create model
            var UserModel = new User() { UserID = userId, UserName = userName, OtherVal = strOtherVal };

            //here call your function to check or post this model to db

        }


 public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string OtherVal { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think you just create a new User, but I don't see where you update an existing one

Comment: I just showed how to pass values from client to server, you can use these values/model to update or insert your entity. Basically this will be your server side logic what to do with model data.

Comment: I think you should change the solution to update/edit the model and not create a new one (as in the question)